# Groovy enhancements not being loaded (date, collections, numbers, etc)

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy project built using Gradle. The issue happens when I build a jar that has all the dependencies (fatJar), so I'm forced to do everyting in the Java way and get none of the Groovy enhancements

When I try to use any of the Groovy enhancements, I get MissingMethodException, this happens on: (just to give some examples)

- new Date().format("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
- [1,2,3].average()

Dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    // Use the latest Groovy version for building this library
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.13'

    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:2.5.13'

    //implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-datetime:2.5.13'

    // Use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'

    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'

    // TODO
    //implementation 'com.github.ppazos:openEHR-OPT:Tag'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

This is the project https://github.com/ppazos/testehr

Not really sure what is going on.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: MissingMethodException no method defined for ....